# How CMS handles postback for integrated web applications?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, content-management-system, opentext

Currently I am working on a project to integrate legacy application (ASP.NET) with a content management system. There are two web servers, one act as cms server which is public facing and other the legacy application website behind the firewall. CMS drive the show to render header, footer, left and right info pans and menu.

My requirement is to show the legacy application aspx pages inside a content area of cms. Everything works fine except postback. The form submits to cms website whereas I want it to postback to legacy application.

How CMS or SharePoint achieve this? For example if a webpart is having a submit button which postbacks, 
 how SharePoint submit the form to webpart? What is the architecture behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking. You're talking about a legacy application hosted in some kind of Iframe and it not being able to post back? Well of course?!

In SharePoint when you build a WebPart you can just use any server side method and it automatically posts back - just regular ASP.NET there, nothing special.
Sometimes a PostBack is called via Javascript for which the `_doPostBack()` Javascript method is used.

Comment: No, not in iframe. CMS shows the aspx html in a content area div. Ofcource after some custom parsing to strip off html and body tags